# Error after adding an action to context api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I keep getting this error 'TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance' and I am not sure whats going wrong. I am using React and the Context API Here is my code. Not sure if I am missing a typo as I have been known to do that before.

[error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slcwW.png)

Store.tsx

```
interface IState {
    episodes: [],
    favourites: []
}

interface IAction {
    type: string,
    payload: any
}

const initialState: IState = {
    episodes: [],
    favourites: []
}


export const Store = React.createContext<IState | any>(initialState)

function reducer(state: IState, action: IAction): IState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
            return {...state, episodes: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}



export function StoreProvider(props: any): JSX.Element {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    return <Store.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Store } from './Store'


export default function App():JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Store)

  useEffect(() => {
    state.episodes.length() === 0 && fetchDataAction()
  })

  const fetchDataAction = async () => {
    const URL = 'https://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=the-office&embed=episodes'
    const data = await fetch(URL)
    const dataJSON = await data.json()
    return dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_DATA',
      payload: dataJSON._embedded.episodes
    })
  }
  console.log(state)

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Rick and Morty</h1>
      <p>Pick your favourite episode</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { StoreProvider } from './Store'


ReactDOM.render(
<StoreProvider>
<App />
</StoreProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error log as well.

Comment: just added a link to the picture of error there is also this ```index.js:1375 The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App (at src/index.tsx:10)
    in StoreProvider (at src/index.tsx:9)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out just had to change `const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(Store)` to `const {state, dispatch} = React.useContext(Store)`